# update column value from another table column value in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables as below:

- `abc`:

  - `id`
  - `icon`
  - `timestamp`
- `xyz`:

  - `id`
  - `dob`
  - `abcId`
  - `icon`
  - `timestamp`

i want to update a `icon` value in `xyz` table with specific `id`. For this i am using below query.

```
update xyz t set image = (select image from abc t1 where id = t.abcId);
```

But this update all the values. Can any one please update this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this query:

```
update xyz t 
set image = 
    (select image from abc t1 where t1.id = t.abcId) 
where t.id="**ID That You Want To Update**";
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add a `WHERE` clause to the `UPDATE` statement, that's why all rows are updated.

Try adding the following at the end of the statement:

```
WHERE t.id = 42
```

Then only the `xyz` with `id` 42 will be updated.